# How to convert this datetime string into a Java date variable?

Tags: java, datetime

```
Sun Jan 09 2011 22:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

I have the above string coming from JavaScript.

How do I convert that into a Java DateTime?

Answer (score 3):

With [SimpleDateFormat.parse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29).  See the [pattern docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) located up at the top of that page to help you figure out what pattern you want to use for your parsing format string.

Comment: he wont be happy with that answer.

Comment: @John you the author of the class?